# How to use different codec on the same TcpStream, as Framed::new() consumes TcpStream?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am currently working on a chat server using tokio with its utilities.
Assume the server receives a connection:

```
let listener = TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:1234").await?;
let (stream, _) = listener.accept().await?;
```

By doing below, I am able to read or write lines:

```
let mut lines = Framed::new(stream, LinesCodec::new());
lines.send("write a line to client").await?;
let string_from_client = lines.next().unwrap();
```

However, if I want to send files, images, etc. I may need to use other codec(`BytesCodec`), while TcpStream is consumed by the constructor of Framed.
How am I able to do that? If there is a solution, how can I drop the TcpStream and disable all Framed(s) after shutdown gracefully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Framed::into_inner`](https://docs.rs/tokio-util/latest/tokio_util/codec/struct.Framed.html#method.into_inner) to get the underlying stream back:

```rust
let mut lines = Framed::new(stream, LinesCodec::new());
lines.send("write a line to client").await?;
let string_from_client = lines.next().await;
let stream = lines.into_inner();
```

Though, be careful, as this drops the internal state of the `LinesCodec` and, more importantly, this drops the state of the `Framed` that contains the read- and write-buffers. So if you for example received `foo\nbar`, read `foo`, and now call `into_inner`, you're discarding `bar` (it's in the read-buffer of the `Framed`).

Your use-case sounds like you might want to implement your own [`Decoder`](https://docs.rs/tokio-util/latest/tokio_util/codec/trait.Decoder.html) and [`Encoder`](https://docs.rs/tokio-util/latest/tokio_util/codec/trait.Encoder.html). The `Decoder` could for example decode into a `enum { Text(String), Bytes(Bytes) }`.

> how can I drop the TcpStream and disable all Framed(s) after shutdown gracefully?

When dropping the `Framed`, you're also dropping the `TcpStream` (it's contained [inside the `Framed`](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/blob/d7b7c6131774ab631be6529fef3680abfeeb4781/tokio-util/src/codec/framed_impl.rs#L21)).